# How to get paragraphs in Flutter textfield or textformfield?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building a form that includes fields for notes. I want the user to be able to hit `enter`/`return` and start a new paragraph.

I am able to create a field that will accept and display large amounts of text. But I specifically want the user to be able to create paragraphs, otherwise their notes are just one long string with no breaks making it hard to read and edit.

I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44616), but was told that I just need to do something like [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44616).

This does not do want I want. I am trying to do something like [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13765).

It looks like this should be possible (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43935). I don't know what I'm missing.

I am building for web, not iOS or Android.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Center(
        child:TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: 10,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: textformfield_demo
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Perhaps this issue occurred only in version `1.10.15`. Try to upgrade Flutter SDK with `flutter upgrade`. Actual version on `dev channel` is `1.10.16`.

Comment: @Spatz, that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a property of flutter to set max and min line. You can set maxLine:(int) Or maxLine: null, here maxLine:(int) restrict user to (int) number of line and  maxLine: null will provide new line text without limit.
As-

```
class MultiLineEt extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MultiLineEt> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>Scaffold(
    body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
       new TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: null,
        ),
  ],
    ) );
}
```

Using ListView to prevent from pixels error